# Video Production outdoor in driveway? Filming me working on my car?

Tags: youtube

I've been planning on shooting a video in my driveway of me working on my car; How do I get the best lighting when I'm going to be filming all day?

I'm going to be welding, on the side of my car, replacing rust, and want to document for youtube. I've done so in the past, but the sun changing directions sucks.

I've thought about buying one of these ez-up tents, to get rid of sun glare, and get a soft box lighting kit to add my own light back in. But what are your thoughts on this? Am I on the right track?

I would close all sides, and drape one side over the portion of the vehicle that I am working on.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the tent you get is white, like the one in the picture, you can point a light up into it, and then the tent becomes a giant soft box. The light loses a lot of energy doing this, because the tent material isn’t designed  to reflect 100% of the light striking it, but the same thing happens to sunlight going in the other direction, and any sunlight coming through the material will diffuse and contribute to the total amount of light. A setup like this runs the risk of being too soft, pushing into flat territory, so you’d want to add a second light to use as your key, and use tent as fill.

If you don’t want to have to buy a second light, you could try rolling up one of the sides of the tent, and using ambient daylight (not direct sunlight) to add contrast to the image.  The amount of contrast will vary through the day, however, and will require you to roll up/down the sides of the tent, assuming the tent sits in direct sunlight all day.

For close-up shots of work being done to the car,  an LED panel would be easier to position, and get in the way less than a large soft box, plus it would double as a work light.  The closer a panel light is to its subject, the softer the light appears, which is why they’re good for closeups.